# I need to create a hierarchy table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As the example above, I need to write a code in python to iterate over the lines of the same table, if the entry on the second column of a certain line is equal to the 10th line of the first column.

I tried the code as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=[[0,2,3],[3,4,6],[2,3,7],[4,5,3]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame (df, columns = ['l1', 'l2','l3'])
df2.columns = range(df2.shape[1])
df3=df2

for i in range(100):
  i=str(i)
  df2.merge(how="inner",left_on=i,right_on="0",right=df3)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u78y2.png)

Comment: It looks like your question is interesting but the provided example is cryptic… could you elaborate by giving a clear input, clear output? and better explain the logic

Comment: input list/table ex: df=[[0,12],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[4,9,10]], so, each line of the list will interact with all the others, if the element first column matches with the second or third element of another line, then the second and third collumn of this line will be apended to the line. the example above will give a result as: df=[[0,1,2],[3,4,5,9,10],[6,7,8],[4,9,10]],